# Get specific info from Perforce submitted changelists

Tags: regex, perforce

I would like to get specific information about submitted change lists from Perforce:

So my goal is to get submitted files and release description:

I will start with something like this:

```
p4 changes -m //depot/main/path/...@2013/02/20,@now
```

This will give me change list number, date, user by whom submitted, changelist description.

But what is the regular expression I can use to also include, or to get only release note, and files included to this change list ?

Any ideas is greatly appreciated...

Comment: The regex would depend on the tool you plan to use - in some cases it will take more than a simple, single, regex. Before you decide, though, take a look at how the output changes when you use the global -s or -z tag options (`p4 -s changes` or `p4 -z tag changes`), that output may be easier to parse for some tools.

Comment: I wanna write a small script to produce the output... so I will not use any other tools

Comment: To include the full change description in the output you can run 'changes -l', but if you need to know which files are in the change you need to run 'p4 describe -s' for each change number that comes back from the 'p4 changes' command.

Comment: @Stanislav: You must use *some* tools, presumably `grep` at least.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're on Unix the most simple approach would be:

```
p4 changes //depot/main/path/...@2013/02/20,@now | awk '{print $2}' | xargs p4 describe -s
```

The `-m` flag from your example requires an argument (the maximum number of changes you want to see).

Comment: Not really - sorry. You could as well use p4web and see the changes there?

Comment: You can install unix-style tools such as awk on Windows. There are a couple of ways, though most people just install Cygwin (then add cygwin's bin directory to their Windows PATH value so the commands are available outside of a cygwin login).